# Pasting numbers into python so that they may be used as an array

Tags: python, excel

Currently I have a large amount of numbers that I am copy and pasting from excel from a column into python and they paste as such:

12
13
14
15
16
...
Each number is on a seperate line.

Currently I am having to backspace in front of a number so that it jumps to the previous line then I insert commas between each number so that I can use this array in my code. These numbers come in quantities of hundreds and it is easier currently to copy and paste into excel and then into python versus saving an excel file with these numbers and referencing the excel file in my script. I am using visual studio code for my editor and I tried alt+v and that didnt work(read that as a shot). Let me know if there is an easy way to get my copy and pasted column into a useable array. Thanks

Comment: use export as csv from excel, and read the file from python, or use one of the libraries that enable you to interact directly with an excel file.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without exporting as csv. I am trying to write this so that others can easily copy and paste their own data without having to save the data as an excel file. (The data does not come from excel, but rather the internet, and is most easily transferred by copy and paste into excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you read in the file. But if that's not an option, I occasionally do something like this with [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) when I want to paste in data quickly (should be able to do with any advanced text editor that allows multiple find/selection):

[image]

Comment: It seems I must use the excel file approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m reading what you are trying to do correctly, in VS Code, you can do essentially what @sundance suggested by holding Alt and dragging your cursor down the different lines to get a multiline cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use excel to transpose the data. copy the range you are wanting to transpose, then paste the column data on a blank sheet using the paste transposed funciton in excel. If your data is too large, 16384 rows, for the column limitations of excel this will cause an error. hopefully this is not the case. Once your data is horizontal you can paste it into python and use this scriptlet to change it into an array.

```
data = input("paste horizontal data here")
print(data)
data = data.split("\t")
print(data)
```

\t is a tab character. This what excel will use to separate the columns.
\n is a newline character.

if your data set it too large to use excel columns and you dont want to break it into separate rows, the next best thing is a text editor like sublime, as Sundance suggested.
I do the sublime editor in a different way though. In sublime, use find and replace to search for the return characters and replace them with tabs or commas or whatver separator you want to use.

I put the brackets first then paste the numbers. then go ctrl + h make sure the *. is selected for find regex.
Find : (\d.\d)\n
Replace: '$1',
there's a space after the comma.
make sure there's a new line after the last number in the list. click replace all or use ctrl + alt + enter to make the replacement. last thing is todelete the last comma and space. copy and paste that into your script.
there you go.

I think it would be much easier for users if the script you are using grabs the info from the web directly using selenium or beautiful soup and pandas data frames if you have to grab web tables. asking a user to do this stuff on sublime isn't the best solution in my view because they just want to click 1 button and complete the task they want done. they don't want to have to go through an algorithm each time they have to do this task. that's what programs and programmers are for.